# Unable to see my controls in MainPage.g.cs of my MainPage.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple question about XAML.

I created a grid element inside another grid and added a textblock and a web browser in it. However, I am unable to access it in MainPage.xaml.cs using their name (e.g. this.LastName) doesn't work. On further debugging, I saw that they are not declared in MainPage.g.cs. Since MainPage.g.cs is auto defined, I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help please? Below is my C# and XAML code. Thanks!
 ========================================================

```
public partial class MainPage : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage {

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Grid LayoutRoot;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Grid ContentPanel;

    internal Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector MainLongListSelector;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Image RefreshIcon;

    private bool _contentLoaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// InitializeComponent
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/Suod;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
        this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));
        this.ContentPanel = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("ContentPanel")));
        this.MainLongListSelector = ((Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector)(this.FindName("MainLongListSelector")));
        this.RefreshIcon = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("RefreshIcon")));
    }
}
```

========================================================

```
     <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="-12,-97,0,97" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="12,100,0,45">
                        <Grid x:Name="CompanyContentGrid">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="LastName" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
                            <phone:WebBrowser Grid.Row="5" Height="400" Name="WebBrowser" Margin="12,-6,24,0" FontFamily="Portable User Interface"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
        <Image Source="/Assets/Refresh.png" Name="RefreshIcon"  Width="80" Height="80" Tap="Image_Tap"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You don't "access" UI elements inside a DataTemplate in procedural code in XAML-based technologies. Whatever you're trying to do, use DataBinding instead of procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your textblock i too deep in xaml code. I think Data Binding should be enough in this situation but there is a way to go around this problem. You have to subscribe this element to some event(like Loaded) and save sender to some property in code behind:

```
<TextBlock Loaded="LastName_Loaded" Grid.Row="0" Name="LastName" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>

public TextBlock lastName;

private void LastName_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   lastName= (TextBlock)sender;
}
```

Now you are able to access this element in code behind.